# eudev was skipped: conflicting distro feature 'systemd' (in DISTRO_FEATURES)

Tags: yocto, openembedded

My recipe needs eudev.

```
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "eudev"
```

but when bitbake it:

it got:

```
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'eudev' (but foo_7.4.5.0.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
eudev was skipped: conflicting distro feature 'systemd' (in DISTRO_FEATURES)
```

Comment: Do you really need to depend on eudev specifically (and not udev which could be provided by systemd as well)?

Comment: actually, I need libudev.so.0, this is a test.

Comment: Please add your machine info in systemd* files (bb | bbappend)

Answer (score 1):

If you want libudev, then DEPEND on udev.  This is provided by either systemd or eudev.